# Как получить число типа float из 2 байтов

Tags: c#, float

Имеются 2 байта.(старший байт и младший) Как получить из них число типа float.

Comment: Имеете ввиду в каком порядке?

Comment: А с чего вы взяли, что эти два байта должны образовать float ?

Comment: @Kromster, ну вроде всё у нас в байтах

Comment: А с чего вы взяли, что эти ***два байта*** должны образовать ***4-байтный*** float ?

Comment: @Андрей. Да. В каком порядке?

Comment: @Kromster, ну так автор хочет "добить" недостающие байты нулями, в чем проблема-то? Там и код показан. Просто он хочет уточнить в начале эти нули должны идти или в конце передаваемого массива.

Comment: @Kromster Имееются 2 байта из них надо получить число float. Ну раз во float 4 байта, поэтому.

Comment: @Андрей Любые 4 байта образуют валидное (или специальное) число типа float. И только ТС знает, откуда он взял свои 2 байта и как их надо расположить и чем дополнить чтобы получить то число, которое ему нужно. *Есть числа с точкой половинной точности, 8-байтные, но опять же, только ТС может сказать, это у него на руках или нет*

Comment: @Андрей Я получаю от контроллера ответ по протоколу Modbus RTU. И эти 2 байта образуют у меня значение некоторого параметра( допустим давление)

Comment: @VictorSayapov отлично, теперь идёте читать документацию к контроллеру и узнаете ***что*** это за 2 байта ***и как*** они образуют значение.

Comment: @Kromster - нафига документация, если все в байтах (как указано выше)

Comment: если это modbus RTU - то нужно брать спецификацию на устройство и смотреть. К примеру, там может быть сказано, что нужно указанное число умножить на некий коеффициент или разделить. А может быть и более сложная формула.

Answer (score 4):

Любые 4 байта образуют валидное (или специальное) число типа float, так что вы можете дополнять нулями с любых сторон и в любых комбинациях.

Но! .. числа с точкой могут иметь разную длину. Возможно у вас т.н. половинный флоат (half float), записываемый в 2 байтах. См. картинку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как было сказано выше, в комментариях, теперь идите читать документацию к своему контроллеру и узнаете что это за 2 байта и как они образуют значение - half float это, или целое с фиксированной точкой, или мантисса/экспонента отдельно, или дробь, или ещё как. Согласно этому, уже смотрите как их надо переводить в стандартный float.

Answer (score -1):

По сведениям MSDN порядок байт зависит от архитектуры компьютера. Архитектуру можно узнать, воспользовавшись статическим полем `BitConverter.IsLittleEndian`

Подробнее читайте раздел комментарии здесь: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.bitconverter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: *Наводящий уточняющий вопрос* Архитектуры какого компьютера, на котором автор пытается их склеить?

Comment: @Kromster, ну конечно, на котором запустит - архитектуру того и получит.

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос.

Comment: Давайте ТС придет и скажет является ли или нет

Answer (score -1):

Структура чисел описана на [Wiki](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D1%81_%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B9_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B9).

Одинарная точно имеет такую структуру:

> S-E-F
>
> S — знак, E — показатель степени, I — целая часть, F — дробная часть
> Так же, как и для целых, знаковый бит — старший.

Размеры полей в битах:

> 1-8-23

Соответственно, если ты подашь данные в этом порядке, то у тебя все должно получится.

Соответсвенно, ты так же можешь из известного тебе числа получить массив байт и посмотреть, как это все устроено.

Comment: Там ведь для преобазования берутся 4 байта. А у меня их 2. В каком порядке их взять. Вот в чем вопрос.

Comment: @VictorSayapov, Если ты говоришь о старшим байте и о младшем, то тебя должны интересовать S и F, а все остальное нулями.

Comment: @iluxa1810 вот есть у него два байта. Какие куски они представляют от трех частей? какой бит из шестнадцати - знак? где экспонента, где мантисса? Детский сад какой-то.

Comment: @Igor, ну в таком случае задача не решаема без уточнений.